# Computing the thickness of branches in a 2D image

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, fiji, image-slicer

I'd like to get a measure of the thickness of branches in an image. The following is the output obtained from Fiji.

[image]

I'd like to compute an average measure of the thickness associated with each edge. By edge, I mean the segment present between any two branching points.

Any directions on how to proceed will be really helpful.

Image source: [ref](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/29262374)

EDIT:
Node is a junction point or the terminal points. Please let me know if it is not clear and if I have to explain it further. For instance, if we skeletonize the above image like the ones shown [here](https://imagejdocu.tudor.lu/plugin/analysis/analyzeskeleton/start), the junctions or terminal points will be nodes. If it helps, I can share a skeletonized version of the above image.

EDIT2:
[image]

```
{1 -> {36.4156, 23.8112, 0.},
 2 -> {83.4779, 151.809, 0.}, 
 3 -> {182.451, 145.504, 0.},
 4 -> {227.385, 86.2469, 0.}, 
 5 -> {311.9, 218.811, 0.},
 6 -> {483.204, 190.795, 0.}, 
 7 -> {601.916, 226.427, 0.},
 8 -> {780.405, 312.889, 0.}, 
 9 -> {974.959, 274.093, 0.},
 10 -> {656.313, 209.944, 0.}, 
 11 -> {815.08, 182.186, 0.},
 12 -> {923.162, 121.453, 0.}, 
 13 -> {353.554, 34.5667, 0.},
 14 -> {479.314, 87.3631, 0.}, 
 15 -> {662.5, 119.5, 0.},
 16 -> {759.72, 99.8905, 0.}, 
 17 -> {539.501, 34.4999, 0.},
 18 -> {712.917, 26.8174, 0.}, 
 19 -> {896.5, 65.5, 0.},
 20 -> {143.654, 379.583, 0.}, 
 21 -> {203.382, 270.926, 0.},
 22 -> {311.084, 354.623, 0.}, 
 23 -> {495.5, 330.5, 0.},
 24 -> {643.872, 319.37, 0.}, 
 25 -> {794.571, 405.533, 0.},
 26 -> {415.864, 397.252, 0.}, 
 27 -> {624.794, 369.389, 0.},
 28 -> {488.5, 276.5, 0.}}
```

Comment: What exactly defines a branch in your image? Do you also have some nodes with it?

Comment: @s.k Node is a junction point or the terminal points. Please let me know if it is not clear and if I have to explain it further

Comment: Have you located the junctions yet?

Comment: I mean, do you have the node coordinates in the image reference frame?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Please check my edit

Comment: @s.k Yes, I do. Please check my dit

Comment: Use distance transformation for image.

Comment: It looks like branch width is encoded by the color. Why not read the color and translate that to a width by table lookup?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Could you please explain a bit more with a pseudo-code, if possible? I'm really new to this field, I'm not sure if I understand you competely

Comment: @AlexAlex Could you please share an example if possible?

Comment: Cris is just saying *"if the line joining two nodes is yellow, it's fat. If it's red it's medium thickness" If magenta, it's thin."*

Comment: @AlexAlex Could you please check the comment posted below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do distance transform.
Multiply the resulting image by the skeleton. See an example. Decomposition the skeleton into segments and average over the segments. This will be the average line thickness.
Matlab/Octave code:

```
a=imread('IW.png');
bw=im2bw(a, 0.1);
skeleton=bwmorph(bw, 'skel', Inf);
D = bwdist(~bw);
imagesc(D.*single(skeleton));
```

[image]

Or this Matlab/Octave code:

```
a=imread('IW.png');
bw=im2bw(a, 0.1);
skeleton=bwmorph(bw, 'skel', Inf);
branchpoints=bwmorph(skeleton, 'branchpoints');
se=strel('disk', 3);
branchpoints=imdilate(branchpoints,se);
segments=skeleton>branchpoints;
segments=bwareaopen(segments, 8);
stats = regionprops(segments,'Centroid', 'PixelIdxList');
centroids = cat(1, stats.Centroid);
D = bwdist(~bw);
hold on
%imagesc(D.*single(skeleton))
imshow(a)
for i=1:numel(stats)
    m(i)=mean(D(stats(i).PixelIdxList));
    text(centroids(i,1),centroids(i,2), num2str(m(i)), 'Color','blue');
end
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you. What I am looking for is an average value of color/ the predominant color of each branch (a branch is a segment between two junctions). In the end, I'd like to assign a single value fo color to each branch. If my understanding is right, the image posted above has this already. Can we translate this result into a table with edge labels( for example edge 1-2  colorcode 6.5) and colors?

Comment: First you need to cut the skeleton into segments. This can be done with the XOR operation (skeleton, 'branchpoints' ).  Then you need to go through the connected components and calculate the average for the segment.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip. Could you please offer some suggestions on how to do this `First you need to cut the skeleton into segments`?

Comment: Thank you. For some reason, when I run the above code in 2019b, I find only a black and white image with text displayed on it. Are you using 2020a? If yes, could you please let me know how to get the same output as shown above in 2019b?

Comment: Version 2017b.  You change first line? File name is correct?  Start on step by step debug mode.

Comment: Ok. Yes, I've changed the file name. I suppose you are using the first image shared by me as the original input.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213057/discussion-between-alex-alex-and-natasha).

Comment: Hi, I tried the code that was shared in the discussion chat on a new image (thickness map from Fiji ([image](https://github.com/DeepaMahm/misc/blob/master/Fig4a_thickness.png)), skeleton generated from Fiji ([image](https://github.com/DeepaMahm/misc/blob/master/Fig4a_skeleton.png)) using this code ([MATLAB code](https://github.com/DeepaMahm/misc/blob/master/thickness_measurement.m)). The values are not displayed on each branch of the network after running the MATLAB code. Could you please have a look?